# How did Rush know that he had gone back in time in SG-U S02E12?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

After the failed use of the stargate in the middle of the star, Rush gets in the shuttle and goes out to meet the Destiny approaching the star in the past.
How did he know that he was in the past and could go do that?

Comment: It can help if you give an episode name and very brief summary (without spoilers, but enough for us to "get" which episode you're talking about).  That way people aren't forced to first Google and find the episode themselves.  (Or a link to the episode description would help, too.)  Some might know the answer but not want to track down which episode it is.

Comment: I was hoping this was about the band...

Answer (score 7):

He didn't know that he was in the past, he was forced to abandon Destiny because the air became toxic. When the other Destiny dropped out of FTL was when he actually realized it.

Comment: NominSim, thank you.  That makes sense.

Comment: I loved this episode. The only thing that didn't make sense to me is that the air was obviously _not_ toxic as it later supported half the crew for like half an hour.